# How to open OAuth popup (window hierarchy)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, oauth, oauth-2.0

The implementation of this part should be pretty straightforward (but it isn't)

I implemented OAuthIODelegate into LoginViewController but the problem is when I run this code:

```
OAuthIOModal *oauthioModal = [[OAuthIOModal alloc] initWithKey:@"the_key" delegate:self];
[oauthioModal showWithProvider:@"facebook"];
```

Then I get this:

> Warning: Attempt to present OAuthIOModal: 0x14ecc8e0 on
>   MenuViewController: 0x14eb8d80 whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

The problem with this is that I'm not even calling this on MenuViewController.

For testing purposes I'm calling LoginViewController from MenuViewController and then from login controller when I press a button I run the code above.

I've tried to find a solution but nothing this specific popped up.

Help would be appreciated.

tnx

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Yes I did. It turned out to be exactly what it said :) basically you need to call LoginViewController using navigationController => [self.navigationController pushViewController:_loginScreen animated:YES];
Then it will be in window hierarchy.
The same applies for the controller from which you call login controller (if there is any) and so on all the way to the root view controller (the first that's presented on application start)

Hope it helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

MenuViewController is set as your root view controller, but it isn't loaded (yet). I presume you're moving between views at this point.

Try putting your code in MenuViewController.m : viewDidLoad . You might need something to shift other business logic around this, but essentially you can't show a popup until the view has loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    OAuthIOModal *oauthioModal = [[OAuthIOModal alloc] initWithKey:@"the_key" delegate:self];
    [oauthioModal showWithProvider:@"facebook"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @button for your answer, however I might not be clear enough when describing situation.
The menu controller was well loaded when I loaded login controller and I call these methods from login controller.
What I don't understand here is why am I getting the warning regarding the screen that is not related to this at all (namely menu controller)?